# Why not Basic Auth everytime instead JWT?

Tags: rest, authentication, hapi.js

I'm in the middle of writing a *RESTFUL API* in Hapi, I could not figure out API authentication methodologies.

Assuming we're using SSL/TLS with HTTP/1.1, why do we need something like JSON Web Token (JWT), where we already have **HTTP Basic Authentication**. We may protect every endpoint with **HTTP Basic Auth**, so we wouldn't even need login routes like `'/login'`.

So, what's the point of those authentication schemes, OAuth's and JWT?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OAuth and JWT use tokens, not passwords.  Tokens are uniquely generated per application and site.  If someone steals a token, they have not stolen your password, and that token is only good for that session only.

Contrast this with basic auth, it's an actual user password.  Not only can they re-use that password whenever they want, they can also use that password with any other service that uses the same password.  Stealing a token doesn't allow that to work.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, we create an abstraction layer in those methodologies to make authentication states temporary hence they will expire over time, where HTTP authentication schemes work with permanent hashes.

There is another problem: Do first request to fetch the token changes over time? I mean, we need to send a request to some endpoint like `/login` in order to get the auth token, does it change? Also, from performance aspect, do we need to make a query to the database in every request in those flows (not forcing you to hold the states in client-side)?

Comment: @Leviathlon - Yes, every time you login the token changes.  Whether or not you hit the database is part of the implementation server-side.  Some might hold that token in cache, along with associated identity information.  Some may hit the database each time.  It's largely up to you and/or the library you're using to implement it.